# Elastic beanstalk has its own cache?

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am using elastic beanstalk with a CakePHP 3 application, I also work with Po files for translations, and in the dashboard, the user can translate the sentences.

I realized that the translation's updates are shown in the frontend ONLY after a new deployment AND ONLY if a **file changes** (for example an HTML file). If I run a deployment only changing the Po files (there is a script that creates the po files with each deployment), the translations are not updated in the server. I double-checked many times that the po files are updated correctly before pushing them (and they are :) ), but the po files in the server (EB) sometimes are not updated (it is a bit random).

I am a bit confused because **the code removes the tmp/cache folder with each deployment** and each time a user updates a translation, but it seems that still has some cache. Maybe an elastic beanstalk cache? Nginx? I do not use Elastic cache or something like that, cake stores the cache in the tmp/cache folder as binaries files as I mentioned above.

Note: When a new deployment is pushed to EB the Po files are generated from scratch populating the sentences from the db. If I check the files generated, all are ok, but the problem is that the server po files are not always updated (this random behavior makes me think that it is a cache issue).

**update**: I also realized that if I add some line to a .ebextension file (for example a simple "ls" command), the po file is updated correctly in the server (I am running a command in there to remove the cache folder with each deployment).

**Platform**: PHP 7.4 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2/3.3.9

Just in case maybe it can help, this is the .ebextension file I run with each deployment:

```
container_commands:

  01-deleteCache:
    command: |
      rm -fr  /var/app/staging/tmp/
      mkdir /var/app/staging/tmp
      mkdir /var/app/staging/tmp/cache
      chown -R webapp:webapp /var/app/staging/tmp
      chmod -R 777 /var/app/staging/tmp
      chmod -R 775 /var/app/staging/src/Locale/
     
      echo "list cache directory to ensure it is empty"
      ls -la /var/app/staging/tmp/cache


 /var/app/staging/plugins/MyPlugin/src/Locale/it_IT/MyPlugin.po
```

**Note**: The **ls -la /var/app/staging/tmp/cache** command returns an empty folder, for that reason I can say that the cake cache was cleared correctly.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found it!!, I was removing the wrong directory, the right one is located in /var/app/current not in staging. Well as I mentioned before I solved for one environment (staging), **but I still have the same problem in production**, and both environments have the same paths etc...